# Function I defined is not cleaning my list properly

Tags: list, pandas, data-cleaning

Here is my minimal working example:

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] #len = 21
list2 = [1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]     #len = 21
list3 = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]  #len = 21
list4 = [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]   #len = 21
```

I have four lists and I want to "clean" my list 1 using the following rule: "if any of list2[i] or list3[i] or list4[i] are equal to zero, then I want to eliminate the item I from list1. SO basically I only keep those elements of list1 such that the other lists all have ones there.

here is the function I wrote to solve this

```
def clean(list1, list2,list3,list4):
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        if (list2[i]==0 or list3[i]==0 or list4[i]==0):
            list1.pop(i)
    return list1
```

however it doesn't work. If you apply it, it give the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):line 68, in clean list1.pop(I)

IndexError: pop index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, I was told Pandas is really good in dealing with data. Is there a way I can do it with Pandas? Each of these lists are actually columns (after removing the heading) of a csv file.

**EDIT**
For example at the end I would like to get: list1 = [4,9,11,15]

I think the main problem is that at each iteration, when I pop out the elements, the index of all the successor of that element change! And also, the overall length of the list changes, and so the index in pop() is too large. So hopefully there is another strategy or function that I can use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a job for pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'l1':list1,
        'l2':list2,
        'l3':list3,
        'l4':list4
        })

no_zeroes = df.loc[(df['l2'] != 0) & (df['l3'] != 0) & (df['l4'] != 0)]
```

Where df.loc[...] takes the full dataframe, then filters it by the criteria provided.  In this example, your criteria are that you only keep the items where l2, l3, and l3 are not zero (`!= 0`).

Gives you a pandas dataframe:

```
    l1  l2  l3  l4
4    4   1   1   1
9    9   1   1   1
12  12   1   1   1
18  18   1   1   1
```

or if you need just list1:

```
list1 = df['l1'].tolist()
```

if you want the criteria to be where all other columns are 1, then use:

```
all_ones = df.loc[(df['l2'] == 1) & (df['l3'] == 1) & (df['l4'] == 1)]
```

Note that I'm creating new dataframes for `no_zeroes` and `all_ones` and that the original dataframe stays intact if you want to further manipulate the data.

**Update:**

Per Divakar's answer (far more elegant than my original answer), much the same can be done in pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list1, list2, list3, list4])
list1 = df.loc[0, (df[1:] != 0).all()].astype(int).tolist()
```

Comment: thank you for answering. As I am not very practical with Panda, what does exactly `df = df.loc[(df['l2'] != 0) & (df['l3'] != 0) & (df['l4'] != 0)]` do?

Comment: well I got my expected output just by scanning with my eyes the 4 lists. Basically if you put the 4 lists in a matrix, with list1 = row1 etc, I would like to get those items in row1 such that all the other items in that column are ones!

Comment: if your output is $,9,12,18$ I reckon that is the correct one, I might have made a mistake counting to be honest ahaha

Comment: If you want the criteria to be that they are all equal to 1, then you would simply replace `!= 0` with `== 0`.  I have a feeling you're going to like pandas.

Comment: thank you a lot, it seems to work perfectly! Pandas seems very powerful, actually reading again your code seems quite readable as well. Would you know any good source or book where I could learn Pandas from?

Comment: pandas has fantastic documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/.  It also has an expert (and incredibly responsive) following here on StackOverflow.  I imagine many of your future questions have already been answered here, so just Google your question and "pandas" and you should be set.  If you can't find your answer, just post a question here - and it seems like you're familiar with MCVEs, so you should be good to go.

Comment: thank you a lot! I will have a look at the documentation!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach with [`NumPy`](http://www.numpy.org/) -

```
import numpy as np

mask = (np.asarray(list2)==1) & (np.asarray(list3)==1) & (np.asarray(list4)==1)
out = np.asarray(list1)[mask].tolist()
```

---

Here's another way with `NumPy` that stacks those lists into rows to form a `2D` array and thus simplifies things quite a bit -

```
arr = np.vstack((list1, list2, list3, list4))
out = arr[0,(arr[1:] == 1).all(0)].tolist()
```

Sample run -

```
In [165]: arr = np.vstack((list1, list2, list3, list4))

In [166]: print arr
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
 [ 1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0]
 [ 0  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1]
 [ 1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1]]

In [167]: arr[0,(arr[1:] == 1).all(0)].tolist()
Out[167]: [4, 9, 12, 18]
```

Comment: nice and elegant I like the second option!

Comment: Divakar - this is a great solution.  This has educated me a bit more on how to do the same with pandas.  I'm going to update my answer based on yours.  Thank you.

Comment: @pshep123 Liked yours too. It's always great to have options, speaking for OP here :)